# Why am I failing to resolve public java objects in jython when using "from javax.mail import *"?

Tags: java, jython, embedded-script

I'm not sure if this is a jython bug or a misunderstanding on some nuances of importing java packages/classes with jython 2.5.2.

I have a jython class that executes jython scripts from java.  One of these scripts just sends out mail.

Snippet of jython script code:

```
from javax.mail import *
from javax.mail.internet import *
from java.util import Properties

props = Properties()
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "path.mydomain.com")
session = Session.getInstance(props,None) # Session can't be resolved
```

So I end up with an exception when trying to resolve Session, which is at javax.mail.Session, and should be covered by the "from javax.mail import * statement"

The Java class that executes the jython looks a bit like this:

```
static {
    PythonInterpreter.initialize(System.getProperties(), new Properties(), new String[0]);
}

void run(String scriptPath){
    String script; 
    // script is read into this string here from path

    PythonInterpreter python = new PythonInterpreter(null, new PySystemState());
    try (
        python.exec(script);
    ) catch (PyException pyEx){
        // catch
    }
}
```

The weird thing is if I execute another jython script with explicit imports, like

```
from javax.mail import Session
```

Then that works fine, but it will now also be able to resolve Session from the previous script.

I'm using jython-standalone from org.python in the maven repository, version 2.5.2.  This code seemed to work just fine in 2.1.  Maybe it's initially failing to create the wrappers when I use "import *"?

(I know I should have explicit imports for performance reasons, but this software executes other people's scripts, so I'm trying to make it work in the meantime.)

Comment: "I know I should have explicit imports for performance reasons" - That's wrong. You won't gain any performance by removing wildcard imports. You'll only make your code easier to understand.

Comment: In the book Jython essentials, page 81, the authors mention that Jython will go through and create wrappers for all the classes in a package you import * from, and bind them both in the current scope and package namespace.  However, the classes are actually loaded lazily.

Comment: Ok, maybe bad from a Jython perspective but definitely not from Java's standpoint :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of searching, I found out this behavior is actually a bug:

http://bugs.jython.org/issue1383